# pgbouncer - failed to restart

Tags: postgresql, pgbouncer

I am logged in to a server and trying to restart pgbouncer.

```
$ /sbin/service pgbouncer restart
Stopping pgbouncer service:                                [FAILED]
pgbouncer already running                                  [FAILED]
```

When I call for pgbouncer status I get:

```
$ /sbin/service pgbouncer status
pgbouncer dead but subsys locked
```

Anyone know how I can properly restart pgbouncer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for a .pid in `/var/run/` and `/var/lock/subsys/` for pgbouncer and delete them. Then you should be able to restart it correctly.

Comment: stupid mistake - needed "su root" first with root pass and then the restart command worked

Comment: Ah, that'd do it too. :)